# Is there a way to center an R plot within a tabPanel in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a shiny app, and the way I have it formatted the plots are way too wide.  I shortened them with the width argument so they look reasonable but I can't figure out how to center them within the tab panel (apparently plotOutput doesn't take an align argument).

```
 tabsetPanel( 
     tabPanel("Plot1", plotOutput("plot1", width="60%")),
     tabPanel("Plot2", plotOutput("plot2", width="60%"))
   )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any Shiny specific way but you can always use css to style output images. Just add `tags$style` with a following content to your UI:

```
"#plot1 img, #plot2 img {
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}"
```

and remove `width="60%"` from `plotOutput`. Excluding `width` it is just a [Bootstrap center-block](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) class. Minimal ui definition could look like this:

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(
        type="text/css",
        "#plot1 img, #plot2 img {
            width: 60%;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }"
    )),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot1", plotOutput("plot1")),
        tabPanel("Plot2", plotOutput("plot2"))
    )
))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand as my experience with this sort of coding is limited, but would this allow you to maintain the tabs produced by the shiny tabPanels?